# Displaying json Response in UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview, response

This is my json response from webservice,

> ```
> ChangedOptions =     (
>             {
>         Descriptions =             (
>             "some text"
>         );
>         Invoice = 0;
>         MSRP = 0;
>         OptionCode = "some text";
>         OptionGroup = "some text";
>         OptionSection = Packages;
>         State = Selected;
>     },
>             {
>         Descriptions =             (
>             "some text"
>         );
>         Invoice = 50;
>         MSRP = 50;
>         OptionCode = "some text";
>         OptionGroup = "some text";
>         OptionSection = Packages;
>         State = Unselected;
>     },
>             {
>         Descriptions =             (
>                   "some text"
>         );
>         Invoice = 0;
>         MSRP = 0;
>         OptionCode = 28F;
>         OptionGroup = "some text";
>         OptionSection = Packages;
>         State = Required;
>     },
>             {
>         Descriptions =             (
>                  "some text"
>         );
>         Invoice = 0;
>         MSRP = 0;
>         OptionCode = 27F;
>         OptionGroup = "CPOS PKG";
>         OptionSection =PowerTrain;
>         State = Excluded;
>     },
> ```
>
> }

i want too fetch the particular array index using the OptionSection

ex: in this response i have to display the Description,Invoice,MSRP,OptionCode,OptionGroup i.e, corresponding to the "Packages" if OptionSection = "Packages" is more than one count i have to display all those things in UITableView

please give any suggestion for that

Answer (score 2):

You should look in to how to use a JSON-parser on iPhone first.
This is a good tutorial: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Comment: I also have a project on github which uses JSON to populate a tableview: https://github.com/Jensen2k/SpillesNaa